# Configure volume indicator in Xubuntu

Tags: sound, xubuntu, pulseaudio, indicator, volume-control

I'm using Xubuntu 17.04 and I have a problem with the volume settings and the volume indicator. When I try to change the volume, the volume indicator opens in front of it and can't change it anymore until it closes.

1) Open volume settings

[image: Open volume settings]

2) Change settings

[image: Change settings]

As you can see on the images the indicator is in front of the slider and I can't slide it anymore. Is it possible to move the indicator or disable it on mouse input. I don't want to remove it completly because I also use keyboard shortcuts to change the settings.

Comment: You can just put the mouse pointer over the volume icon in the panel and scroll.

Comment: No, I can't. When the indicator is there I can't do anything. I can click on it, I can scroll or slide. Nothing changes until it disapears.

Comment: Ah, I understand. But I don't have everytime a mouse with scroll wheel.

Comment: You can use two fingers in your touchpad to "scroll"

Comment: That are workarounds. I want to use these sliders because there I have different options like microphone and different audio devices. I don't want to scroll. I have an old laptop without multitouch pad

Answer (score 0):

With `xfce4-notifyd-config` I can configure the position and the behaviour of the osd. When I move it somewhere else it works.